# IBM worklight Authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

What are the differences between the form based Authentication and Adapter based authentication in IBM worklight which is best for security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between Form and Adapter Based Authentication is that Form Based Authentication is using MobileFirst internal classes and methods, and When using Adapter Based Authentication you are responsible for the authentication procedures (which should be located inside an adapter) - you only declare in the securityTest what procedures to use for login and logout.